# Using two wands at a time in Harry Potter

Tags: harry-potter

It's quite common in *Harry Potter* that two wands obey one wizard if disarmed by *Expelliarmus* spell.

Has anyone ever used two wands to cast a spell at the same time in the *Harry Potter* films?

Comment: Are you asking about the films only or (as your title suggests) the greater *Harry Potter* universe in general? In the latter case, your question would be more appropriate on [scifi.se].

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Am asking about films only.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156068/are-there-an-witches-or-wizards-that-are-known-to-dual-wield-wands

Comment: @Napoleon Still, surely information from the wider Potterverse would be acceptable to support an answer even on this site? I don't understand why you edited out the note in revision 6.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Because a statement like that brings us exactly into the questionable territory where people will spam this question with weird references to things that never actually happened. It would just be another pointer to the truth that this answer is ultimately asking about the wider *Harry Potter* universe to begin with. Of course if the explanation of *how* or *why* that's possible draws from source canon, that's totally fine. But if we want the core of the question *wether it ever happened* to work, then we have to concentrate on the films for that.

Comment: @Napoleon Hmm, I see - fair enough. "Yes, this happened in the films, and it's possible because of such-and-such covered in the books" would be a good answer, but "Yes, this happened in the books" not so much so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It's quite common in Harry Potter that two wands obey one wizard if disarmed by Expelliarmus spell.

Well ... Potterverse wandlore is a bit more complicated than that. Disarming another wizard using *Expelliarmus* can count as 'defeating' them, causing ownership of their wand to pass to you (see: Draco disarming Dumbledore, Harry disarming Draco, and ownership of the Elder Wand passing through them). However, the Elder Wand notwithstanding, most wands will "obey" any sufficiently skilled wizard who uses them, not just the wizard who's 'bonded' with them (see: Harry using Hermione's wand for a while after his own broke).

> Has anyone ever used two wands to cast a spell at the same time in the Harry Potter films?

**Yes.** Harry casts a double-wand *Stupefy* on Lucius Malfoy at Malfoy Manor in *Deathly Hallows Part 2*, using the wands he wrested from Draco. It happens at 2:25 through this video:

Comment: I followed Paulie_D's reference. It points to an answer given on [scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/can-a-wizard-use-more-than-one-wand). But am not sure if that spell originated from two wands.

Comment: @Rahul Harry definitely used two wands in the book. If you look carefully, he also did in the film (you can see them forming a sort of V-shape in his hand).

Comment: I saw two wands. But origin of spells from two wands is not shown. It's unclear. And I guess this is the only instance when someone is holding two wands while casting spells. So I will give it to you.

Comment: Even the Elder Wand obeys non-owners. It just doesn't provide them with its full power, and it won't allow itself to be used against its owner.

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of. A wizard can possess more than one wand at a time (perhaps he used Expelliarmus), but there are no incidents of multi-wand usage that I can recall.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71636)

Comment: @AJ, this does answer the question. The question asks if a wizard has used two wands at once, and this answer clearly says that they have not.

Comment: thank you for defending me and my (hopefully competent) answer. I am only trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

I have found second instance where two wands are used by one wizard while casting spell.

This happens at Godric's Hollow when Harry and Hermione are attacked by Nagini. Harry drops his wand in fight which is then picked up by Hermoine. When Nagini attacks again Hermione casts spell having her and Harry's wand in her hand due to which curse rebounds and [Harry's wand breaks.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_at_Godric%27s_Hollow_(1997))

> Harry’s wand was also revealed to be broken beyond repair, probably as a result of Hermione’s ricocheting Blasting Curse.

You can see Hermione picking up Harry's wand while still holding her want and casting spell with both wands after 2:37

Comment: Your video link is dead.